# Can not disable cookies for HTTPS pages

Tags: session-cookies, jsessionid

In Firefox v36 (Windows) I set the Privacy / History option to "Never Remember History", but they still seem to be used for HTTPS pages. For example the page https://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled claims I have cookies enabled.

It is similar in IE11. I set the Privacy setting to max (Block All Cookies), but JSESSION cookie based HTTPS sites continue to work. The F12 / Network panel shows in the details that the cookie is sent with each request. https://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled on the other hand here claims cookies are not enabled.

Am I missing something obvious?

PS: I also visited http://www.whatarecookies.com/cookietest.asp and http://www.arecookiesenabled.com/ and they both claim I have cookies enabled in Firefox (meanwhile updated to v37). Note they both are regular HTTP sites. In IE11 they again report both NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the "Never Remember History" option does not turn off cookies. To turn off cookies, it must be set to "Use custom settings for history" and then deselect the "Accept cookies from sites" option.

Maybe there is a similar way for IE?